# Asynchronous Trigger vs Trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, audit, service-broker

I have a table `table1`. I want to create the audit of that table using trigger on each insert, update and modify events.

In this table we generally don't perform bulk update, delete or insert. But sometimes thousands of records get modified. I just want to know which approach is efficient here.

1. simple triggers
2. asynchronous triggers using service broker

Do asynchronous triggers using service broker perform well for less no of inserts, updates and deletes?

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server does not really offer asynchronous triggers. All you can do is have a normal, synchronous, trigger and in this trigger use [`SEND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188407.aspx) to send a message to a Service Broker service hosted on a queue with an attached activated procedure and trigger this activated procedure to run, after the transaction that triggered the original synchronous trigger commits. This makes sense if the trigger 'action' is costly and it should be deferred, or if the action does some something like a HTTP web service request and it should ensure that the request happens only post-commit. But because the original `SEND` that puts everything in motion must occur in a synchronous trigger, an async trigger based on Service Broker is still subject to the original restrictions the sync trigger had (eg. it [may not fire on bulk insert](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187640(v=sql.105).aspx)).

A second thing to consider is that moving to an 'async' Service Broker backed trigger has a cost. To send the notification message and RECEIVE it, you must run at least 1 insert, 2 updates and 1 delete (the underlying operations that represent the `SEND` and the `RECEIVE`). You will also have to deal with the async anomalies: by the time your 'async' trigger runs, the data may have well changed.

Personally, for data audit, I would look more toward [Change Tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx) and [Change Data Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx).

Comment: once i send the message,atleast i don't have to wait for the response,and my transaction is not blocked